# Is it possible to use a global variable from a component in another component in angular 5?

Tags: angular

a question that involved my mind is: Is it possible to define a global variable in a component and set value to it and use this in another component. Actually I know I can do it via service but I want a way without using service, just by something like import or declare or ..., I don't know. Could you please help me. This is my variable that I want to use it in another component:

```
export class AdminComponent {

currentUser: any;
isAdvisor: boolean;

constructor() {
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
if (this.currentUser && this.currentUser.role === 4) {
   this.isAdvisorr = true;
  }
 }
}
```

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

**No** you cannot just share a variable across components, you need a SharedService between to components to communicate.

if it's just like a configuration then you can have it in config.ts and import it in two components.

Comment: thank you for reply. But I thought by using provider it is possible.

Comment: providers are services yes its possible via service or kind of config file

Comment: Do you think its better to use a service for global variables that use a lot in a project or define in each component separately?

Comment: if its a constant keep it in your environment.ts or config.ts else keep using service

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's technically possible with an exported variable. But admin component must be instantiated before you use the value in another component.

**Note** It'd be better to use a service

**admin.component.ts**

```
export let isAdvisor: boolean;


export class AdminComponent {

currentUser: any;

constructor() {
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
if (this.currentUser && this.currentUser.role === 4) {
   isAdvisorr = true;
  }
 }
}
```

**other.component**

```
import {isAdvisorr} from '../admin.component'

//use value here
let advisor = isAdvidorr;
```